# Why binding is needed in ES6 react classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In new React ES6 classes `this` needs to be binded as stated here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding
for eg:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }
  tick() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The explanation for this is because it's the default behaviour, however if I make an ES6 class and then I make a new instance of it `this` will be binded

```
import React from 'React'

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
    }
    foo () {
      console.log('bar')
    }
    hello() {
      this.foo()
    }
}

var test = new Test()
test.hello()
// > bar
```

Why binding is needed in React then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need set `this` to methods in case, for example, if you need pass function reference to event handlers, however you don't need set `this` for every method.,

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }

  tick() {
    // this refers to Counter
  }

  fn() {
    // this refers to Counter
  }

  withoutBind() {
    // this will be undefined or window it depends if you use "strict mode" or not
  }

  render() {

    this.fn(); // this inside this method refers to Counter

    // but if you will do like this
    const fn = this.fn;
    fn(); // this will refer to global scope


    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.tick}>1</button>
      <button onClick={this.withoutBind}>2</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36551/)

Answer (score 3):

Classes in ES6 are functions. When you instantiate a class, you get an object. For all the methods in your class, if you used `this` inside them, it refers to the object that owns the method.

But it is confusing when you extract the method because the context changes. Examples:

```
let foo = Counter()
foo.tick()
```

If you call `foo.tick()`, `this` belongs to the object foo. Cool.

But watch this:

```
tickFunc = foo.tick()
tickFunc()
```

You detached the function from the original object, now the function invocation happens where `this` inside `tickFunc()` refers to the global object.

So why do you need to bind your methods in React? You do it because most of the times we are passing the method **references** either to the event handlers or as props to components. When you pass references of your methods, they become detached functions and their context changes. To solve that, you use `bind()` in the constructor.

Comment: An excellent resource for REALLY understanding `this` and function contexts : https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/