# how to set value on button click in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I want to change the state value on button click using react js.I am able to get click event .But the set value not updated why .I used this

```
btnClick(){
    alert('---')
  //  this.setState({data: 'nannsd'});
     this.state ={data: 'sds'};
  }
```

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/MydPJM

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
    this.state ={data: 'test'};
  }
  btnClick(){
    alert('---')
  //  this.setState({data: 'nannsd'});
     this.state ={data: 'sds'};
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      hello {this.state.data}
      <button onClick={this.btnClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  }

}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: When you use ES6 classes, you have to bind this on your handlers. e.g., in your constructor add `this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309636/why-binding-is-needed-in-es6-react-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1) Outside the constructor, you should call `setState` (instead of directly setting state). It looks like you probably tried this since it's commented out.

2) You need to bind `this`, so that you have the right value inside `btnClick`.

Here's a quick fork of your codepen with this fixed up. http://codepen.io/juliepagano/pen/xVNyrO

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={data: 'test'};
  }

  btnClick(){
    alert('---')
   this.setState({data: 'nannsd'});
     // this.state ={data: 'sds'};
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      hello {this.state.data}
      <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>click</button>
    </div>
  }

}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```